Every Angular unit tests fail on init when added @ContentChildren with component type
I've recently added @ContentChildren to one of my components which are reused throughout the whole application and now I can't get rid of unit tests fail. It fails on init with error:
An error was thrown in afterAll
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ContextualMenuComponent')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ContextualMenuComponent')
    at Module.ContextualMenuComponent

Component looks like this now:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-wrapper',
  templateUrl: 'table-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['table-wrapper.component.scss'],
})
export class TableWrapperComponent {
  @ContentChildren(ContextualMenuComponent, { descendants: true }) contextMenus: QueryList<ContextualMenuComponent>;

What's interesting, when I change @ContentChildren(ContextualMenuComponent) to e.g. @ContentChildren('templateRef') unit tests pass but I can't get reference to those components. So definitely, problem is in using ComponentType in ContentChildren.
Do you have any clues what should I do in such case?

Could you try adding ContextualMenuComponent to the testBed, might pass after that?

It fails in unit test init. So I can't just add it to TestBed. I tried to add module which got declaration and export of this component to getTestBed().initTestEnvironment() but still fails

please share a minimal code stackblitz where the issue happens, atleast share the full stack trace so that others can help you, if possible the code, that causes the error on the stacktrace!

It's really hard to make some minimal stackblitz from this project because it got lots of dependencies. I'll try but don't know how much time it will take :/
